# how to delete a primary key which is having auto increment

Tags: sql

i tried two codes to delete  primary key,here am posting my two codes.please help me.

```
    1.    ALTER TABLE User1
   DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Users__1788CCACD82F68B5

  2.ALTER TABLE PK__Users__1788CCACD82F68B5 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
these was error for the first code //Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
 these was the error for second ode//ALTER TABLE PK__Users__1788CCACD82F68B5 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: How is it a C, JavaScript, jQuery, or asp.net question?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this? The answer may change based on the desired outcome.